# Decomposing interval in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

The book I am using states the following result with the respective demonstration:

Let $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open set and $E \Subset \Omega$ ([Compact embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_embedding)). Show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ exist $I_n$, $n=1,2,3...$ open interval such that $I_n \subset \Omega$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $E \subset \bigcup _{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_n$ and 
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text{Vol}(I_n) < m^*(E)+ \epsilon.
$$

**Proof**:  Take $\epsilon >0$ exist $I'_n$, $n=1,2,3...$ such that $E \subset \bigcup _{n \in \mathbb{N}} I'_n$ and 
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text{Vol}(I'_n) < m^*(E)+ \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ 
(this goes straight from the definition of external measure by the infimum of volumes). For each $n$ we decompose:

$$\overline{I'_n}= J_{n,1} \cup J_{n,2} \cup...\cup J_{n,k_n}$$

where each $J_{n,k}$ is compact set and

$$\text{Vol}(I'_n)= \text{Vol}(J_{n,1})+...+\text{Vol}(J_{n,k_n}), \text{   diam}(J_{n,k})< \frac{1}{2} d(E,\mathbb{R}^n- \Omega)$$
...

How do I build or show the existence of these $J_{n,k_n}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use $d$ for the dimension of the ambient space $\Bbb R^d$. I understand that each $I'_n$ is an interval. Fix an integer $M$ and decompose $I'_n$ into $M^d$ subintervals, where the length of each side of the subinterval is the length of the parallel side of $I'_n$ divided by $M$. The diameter of each subinterval is the diameter of $I'_n$ divided by $M$. Tou can make it as small as you wish by taking $M$ large enough.

Comment: Are you using that $I'_n$ is bounded?

Comment: Yes of course, it is an interval with finite volume.

Comment: Very good, but I think wanted to decompose $\overline{I'_n}$. But i understood how it does.

Comment: The same procedure decomposes $\overline{I'_n}$.